# TableAdapter Update Fails

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset, tableadapter

I am trying to update user password in userPassword column from tbUsers table.

I am getting the following error when I click in the "Confirme Button": Object reference not set to an instance of an object - NullReferenceException was unhandled

It says I need to instantiate something but I don't know what. I already have the tableAdapter instantiate.

Thanks for you help!

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Library.DataBase.dsLibraryTableAdapters;
using Library.DataBase;    

tbUsersTableAdapter tableAdapterUsers = new tbUsersTableAdapter();
dsLibrary.tbUsersDataTable dataTableUsers;

private void btnConfirm_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbUsersRow = (dsLibrary.tbUsersRow)dataTableUsers.FindByIdPeopleIdUser(value1, value2);
    tbUsersRow.userPassword = txtNewPassword.Password.ToString(); <- ERROR HERE
    tableAdapterUsers.Update(dataTableUsers);
}
```

Comment: possibly `txtNewPassword` doesnt have a `.Password` property so it is treated as an object which happens to be null.  what is it? and what is "something" it complains about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The txtNewPassword does have a .Password property, I have used it before.

The error is: 

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  Source=Library

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this seems to have solved the problem.

Thanks everyone!

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Library.DataBase.dsLibraryTableAdapters;
using Library.DataBase;    

tbUsersTableAdapter tableAdapterUsers = new tbUsersTableAdapter();
dsLibrary.tbUsersDataTable dataTableUsers;

private void btnConfirm_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     dataTableUsers = tableAdapterUsers.getDataByUserName(lblUser.Content.ToString());
     tbUsersRow = (dsLibrary.tbUsersRow)dataTableUsers.Rows[0];
     tbUsersRow.userPassword = txtNewPassword.Password.ToString();
     tableAdapterUsers.Update(dataTableUsers);
}
```